# Can't convert an array

Tags: arrays

can anyone tell me why this isn't working: It says it cannot convert a double[] to double.

```
for(int i = 0; i < tickerlength; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < priceLength; j++)
            {
                double[] pricevariable = prices[i][j];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: How is prices defined. And what language is this?

Comment: the language is java, excuse me

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prices[i][j]` is a double

`double[] pricevariable` is a double array

if you take off the brackets to get `double pricevariable` the error will go away

not sure if thats what you want it to do though.

if instead you wanted to add `prices[i][j]` to the array called `pricevariable` then you need to declare it OUTSIDE of the loop, then make a third loop, and then insert `prices[i][j]` into that array one at a time like this

```
pricevariable[k] = prices[i][j];
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that `prices` is not a 3-dimentional array and that you're trying to put a `double` in a `double[]`

You're declaring `pricevariable` as an array of double, rather than the double you're putting into it.
for the short answer change this

```
double[] pricevariable = prices[i][j];
```

to this

```
double pricevariable = prices[i][j];
```

Comment: From looking at the quality of this code why would you assume any of those things

Comment: @aaronman because of the error message

Comment: I was was just kidding, good answer

Comment: @aaronman now that I think about it, The error should have been `cannot convert double to double[]`  It's likely that the OP mistyped the error, but I'm a little uncertain now

Comment: thank you, i was thinking in the opposite way.